# scdf-server service url not responding

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-dataflow-ui

I have scdf installed via kuberbetes using minikube. All the pods along with services are in running state. Now I want to access scdf dashboard. As per documentation I got it from:

`./minikube service --url scdf-server`

`http://192.168.225.22:30731`

Now If I am trying to access this ip from browser, its refusing to connect. Please help here.[image]

**Edit:**

Done via NodePort as well, still getting same error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are deploying your SCDF/Skipper services as `LoadBalancer` types and the External-IP status `pending` suggests you don't have a load-balancer setup that works for minikube (like metalLB on minikube).

On minikube, I would go with `NodePort` as the service type instead of `LoadBalancer`. This would at least get you going with the local accessibility.

Comment: Hi Gopinathan, Thanks for replying. I have done it via NodePort as well, shared edit in question itself. I am still getting same error, can you please help in resolving this.

Comment: From the screenshot you shared, the SCDF server isn't ready yet. You can check to see why it is still starting up.